# Increase number of fingerprint attempts

Tags: security, fingerprint

Is there any way to increase the number of allowed fingerprint attempts before PIN etc is demanded? I'm comfortable using adb shell if necessary.

Comment: At least until Android 7, an Xposed module named Fingerprint Enabler was able to do that. Not sure if it supports higher Ándroid versions (7 was the last running on the only device I had with a fingerprint scanner).

Comment: Is that something that can be done without rooting or bootloader unlocking or whatever?

Comment: No, definitely not. And I'd be very surprised if there's a non-root solution to that.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like it's not possible without changing the source code, not even on a rooted device. The max number of attempts is hardcoded at line 43 of [LockoutFrameworkImpl.java](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/biometrics/sensors/fingerprint/hidl/LockoutFrameworkImpl.java) (and stored in the constant field `MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS_LOCKOUT_TIMED`), and the number of failed attempts is stored in the `mFailedAttempts` private field, declared at line 69.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Seems like a crappy way of doing things. I could see the logic if fingerprint sensors were 100% reliable, but they're far from it.